# Laravel orderBy date is not working when using paginator

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel and am struggling to figure this one out.I am trying to order my posts by date and also use the paginator. Whenever I remove the paginator. it orders by date, but adding it back in orders by id, I think?

My model

```
class Post extends Model
{
    //

protected $dates = ['date'];
}
```

My controller method

```
public function show()
    {

        $posts = Post::orderBy('date','desc')->get();


        return view('welcome',['posts' => Post::paginate(5)], compact('posts'));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're essentially retrieving all posts and then paginating them, after retrieving all posts and ordering them.

Your code breaks down like this:

```
public function show()
{

    // retrieve posts and order them by date
    $posts = Post::orderBy('date','desc')->get();

    // retrieve posts again and paginate them
    return view('welcome',['posts' => Post::paginate(5)], compact('posts'));
}
```

You have two options --

Get posts, order them, paginate them, and store them in a variable that you pass to your view:

```
public function show()
{

    $posts = Post::orderBy('date','desc')->paginate(5);


    return view('welcome', compact('posts'));
}
```

Or get the posts, order them and paginate them while passing them to the view:

```
public function show()
{

    return view('welcome',[ 'posts' => Post::orderBy('date','desc')->paginate(5) ]);
}
```

Comment: OH..Ha. That makes sense. Thank you. Although the first option didn't work. The second one works great. The first option gave me an exception.

Comment: Had a typo in the first, should work now. I prefer the first just because I like to be more verbose with variables.

Comment: What was the typo in the first I didn't see a difference?

Comment: You do not call `get()` after `paginate()`. Paginate already returns results (LengthAwarePaginator instance)

Comment: Cool, got the first option working which I prefer to look at, Thanks again.

Comment: @Ryan I forgot a $.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other column/s specifically the ***created_at*** or ***updated_at***. I tried my customized column datetime as my ***orderingBy*** but it doesn't worked, so I used another column(***updated_at***) wherein I just want to get the updated records descendingly and I noticed that it can be use as my solution and it works fine in my query.

```
->orderBy('updated_at','DESC')->get();
->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();
```