# Order by created_at not working with Eloquent models

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I have a little issue when trying to order records by created_at column when using Eloquent Models. The ordering works by **date** but not by **time**. Example if I have 3 records with created_at values:

- 2017-07-04 07:16:33
- 2017-07-04 05:35:01
- 2017-07-04 05:27:48

  I have the same output when using orderby('created_at', 'desc') or 'asc'. Ordering however works if i have for example
- **2017-07-04** 05:27:48
- **2017-07-03** 06:35:50

Ordering works also when I use raw queries. The issue is present only when I use Eloquent Model.

Has anyone any idea why is this happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your schema code?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki here is what I have in my controller :  $connections = Connection::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);

Comment: I mean your migration file! any way try this : `$connections = Connection::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);`

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki Here is the schema in my migration file:

  Schema::create('connections', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('offer_id')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('offer_id')->references('id')->on('offers')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

Comment: nothing  is wrong with your code! its weird.  put your full code in your answer

Comment: take a look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39174377/laravel-orderby-date-is-not-working-when-using-paginator

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki I tried the solution provided in the post, but it still doesn't order the records in desc order, it just gets the **last** 10 records when using pagination. The orderby is not working as it should even when I use get instead of paginate.

Comment: try this: $connections= Connection::latest('created_at')->paginate(10);

Comment: @Leo_Kelmendi it gets the last 10 records, but **does not** order them in desc

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki even if i try:  Connection::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10); by primary key the records are still not ordered -_- hmm weird

Comment: @Katerina try this option as well:  $connections= Connection->goupBy('created_at')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')>paginate(10);

Comment: @Katerina Would you please share your controller method code.

Comment: @JahidMahmud here is the method code: `public function index() { $connections = Connection::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10); return view('connections', compact('connections')); }` If I run the generated sql in mysql it works just fine, but it's not working in laravel

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki Could there be some possibility that the issue raises because there are foreign keys (relations) with 2 other tables/Models??

Answer (score 1):

Ohh it was my bad! I solved the issue, it wasn't a problem on server side when getting the data, but on client side because I used 'dataTables'

Comment: can you please explain what was the actual issue ? Im facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Laravel you use. But it is better to convert datetime value in php into [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) type for ordering and filtering. Please try to convert the values first and then order them. Good luck with your code.

Regards,

Andy Ba

Comment: I use Laravel 5.3, and although I'm new with Laravel, when using orderBy with Eloquent Models, it's default way of ordering records. Thanks anyway